# Error while deploying ear on jboss wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

18:27:43,339 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BServices-1.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BServices-1.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "B2BServices-1.war" of deployment "B2B-1.ear"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.b2b.services.rest.RestClientForNCPCInvoiceFeed with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BServices-1.war:main" from Service Module Loader
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
            at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
            ... 5 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/b2b/invoice/feed/service/InvoiceFeedService
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
            ... 10 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.b2b.invoice.feed.service.InvoiceFeedService from [Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BServices-1.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
            ... 15 more

```
    18:27:43,346 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment B2BDevelopmentTools-1.war
    18:27:43,352 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class com.nccb2b.common.taglib.InvTextTag in Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/InvTextTag (Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/struts/taglib/html/TextTag
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    18:27:43,353 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class com..nccb2b.common.taglib.rbtag.RBTextTag in Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/rbtag/RBTextTag (Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/InvTextTag (Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/struts/taglib/html/TextTag
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    18:27:43,353 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "B2B-1.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/rbtag/RBTextTag (Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/InvTextTag (Module "deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/struts/taglib/html/TextTag
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more
    18:27:43,439 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
        "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BServices-1.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BServices-1.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"B2BServices-1.war\" of deployment \"B2B-1.ear\"
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.b2b.services.rest.RestClientForNCPCInvoiceFeed with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BServices-1.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/b2b/invoice/feed/service/InvoiceFeedService
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.b2b.invoice.feed.service.InvoiceFeedService from [Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BServices-1.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"B2B-1.ear\"
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/rbtag/RBTextTag (Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link com/nccb2b/common/taglib/InvTextTag (Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/struts/taglib/html/TextTag",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BEJB-1.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BEJB-1.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"B2BEJB-1.jar\" of deployment \"B2B-1.ear\"
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.circulationb2b.hostpub.bean.HostpubManagerBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BEJB-1.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sapient/framework/sql/GeneralSqlException
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sapient.framework.sql.GeneralSqlException from [Module \"deployment.B2B-1.ear.B2BEJB-1.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"
        },
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BServices-1.war\".POST_MODULE",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"B2B-1.ear\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BDevelopmentTools-1.war\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BEJB-1.jar\".POST_MODULE"
        ],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BDevelopmentTools-1.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"B2B-1.ear\".\"B2BDevelopmentTools-1.war\".beanmanager]",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"B2B-1.ear\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"B2B-1.ear\".beanmanager]",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"B2B-1.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"B2B-1.ear\".beanmanager]"
        ]
    }
        (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."B2B-1.ear"."B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "B2BWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "B2B-1.ear"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the question? I assume it's "why am I seeing this error?". If so we need more details and the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins. What am I doing wrong? My deployment is failing is because I am doing something wrong in defining dependencies and class loading??

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins can you please help me with this error?

Comment: Well the cause is `WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.b2b.services.rest.RestClientForNCPCInvoiceFeed `. I'm not sure what the issue is though. Maybe you need to rebuild the application. Possibly even compile it with Java 8, though it shouldn't matter.